# Cannot launch terminal or nautilus in 18.04

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal, 18.04

After upgrading to 18.04, I cannot launch terminal or nautilus from the favorites side bar. Xterm, however, is fine, and from there I can execute at least nautilus. Running `gnome-terminal` in the xterm window do nothing, except the warning `"AT-SPI: Could not obtain desktop path or name"`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> won't start the terminal, either. Nothing happens.

PS: I went from Ubuntu 16 through Ubuntu 17.10 without really using 17, perhaps I had the problems there, too.

Comment: watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6wWDMZLX5M) may be it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem
Include the Text Editor, file Manager (Nautilus) , Terminal,... not worked and also the sound after Login didn't work too.

After Upgrading OS , reinstall the  Nautilus, .... witch is didn't help

Finally, by remove the "Google chrome remote desktop" is solved for me.
By Command : **sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop**

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question. It seems that the problem had something to do with old configuration files. I cleaned out a lot of stuff in the "dot" directories, as per hints elsewhere, and now it works as intended.

Comment: Looking at the userids, this is not "your own question" ...

Comment: In fact it is; I just did not understand the different ways of logging in to this forum.